# Impressão de uma sequência de números formatado de 3 em 3 separados por traço

Tags: java, string, java-8

Digamos que eu tenha a seguinte entrada `String S = "00-44  48 5555 8361"` e que preciso retornar essa cadeia de caracteres dividida de 3 em 3, separadas por "-", da seguinte maneira:

> Saída: 004-448-555-583-61

A quantidade de caracteres pode variar. Abaixo o seguinte escopo:

```
public class Solution{
    public static String solution(String S){
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String S = "00-44  48 5555 8361";   
        System.out.print(solution(S));

    }

}
```

De uma forma eficaz, como resolver isso em Java 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex faz mágica:

```
class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "00-44  48 5555 8361";
        System.out.println(solution(s));
        String s2 = "00-44  48 5555 8361 xxx 1";
        System.out.println(solution(s2));
        String s3 = "12345";
        System.out.println(solution(s3));
    }

    public static String solution(String s) {
        return s.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "").replaceAll("...", "$0-").replaceAll("-$", "");
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
004-448-555-583-61
004-448-555-583-611
123-45
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/6afWw5)

Explicação:

- O [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) é um método que opera sobre três strings: A instância sobre a qual o método é chamado (A), o primeiro parâmetro (B) e o segundo parâmetro (C). Esse método procura por ocorrências da expressão regular de B dentro da string A e as substitui por C, retornando o resultado após serem feitas todas as substituições. Referências denotadas com `$` podem ser usadas em C para referenciar grupos definidos em B.
- O `replaceAll("[^\\d]", "")` utiliza a expressão regular `[^\\d]`. Esta expressão regular serve para representar qualquer coisa que não for um número. O trecho `\\d` é o que representa um número. O `[^ ... ]` indica todos os caracteres exceto os que estão entre o `[^` e o `]`. Logo, `[^\\d]` representa todos os caracteres, exceto os numéricos. Assim sendo isso, isso vai substituir qualquer caractere que não seja um número pela string vazia. Ou seja, isso serve para arrancar todos os caracteres não-numéricos da string.
- O `replaceAll("...", "$0-")` utiliza a expressão regular `...`. O `.` representa qualquer caractere, logo `...` são três caracteres. Como a expressão regular anterior já eliminou os não-numéricos, então isso daqui encontra os dígitos em grupos de três em três. Logo, essa expressão substitui cada trio de caracteres numéricos pelo que é representado por `$0-`. Ocorre que `$0` representa tudo o que a expressão regular encontrou, que no caso é os três caracteres encontrados. Assim sendo, isso vai substituir cada três caracteres por esses mesmos caracteres seguidos de um `-`.
- Pode ser que sobre um `-` no final, tal como no caso do `"00-44  48 5555 8361 xxx 1"`. Por isso temos o `replaceAll("-$", "")`. A expressão regular `-$` significa um `-` seguido do fim da string (que é representado por `$`). Isso significa que o traço que estiver no final da string (se houver) vai ser substituído por uma string vazia. Ou seja, deletado.

Comment: Resolveu, sua resposta foi incrível!

Comment: Esse redux faz mágica, olha a quantidade de linhas de códigos! Muito eficiente sua solução. Muito Obrigada!

Comment: @mayssalns Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 